# How to flip even/odd page style?

Tags: koma-script, double-sided

I write a document that is to be printed 2-on-1 (on A4 paper) so double-sided layouts seem reasonable, e.g. for margins. Therefore, I use `scrartcl` with `twoside`.

My problem is that this assumes that odd pages are on the right and even on the left. This is reasonable when printing leaflets (i.e. first page is cover) but that is not the case for me.

Therefore, I want to flip everything. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Check if `twoside=semi` is more suitable for you.

Comment: @ThorstenDonig Thanks, but that leaves me with oneside margins and the parts that are set up for double-sided layout are still the "wrong" way around.

Comment: It would help a lot if you would post a Minimum Working Example. As it is, you are expecting people to supply everything, even `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Comment: @karlkoeller I did not have time to try yet, sorry. I'll let you know!

Answer (score 5):

Let's suppose that your document is like this one, with also headings and footers:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum} % only for the example

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\lipsum[1-4]

\subsection{A subsection}

\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

with this output:

[image]

To flip the margins, you can do:

```
\let\tempmargin\oddsidemargin
\let\oddsidemargin\evensidemargin
\let\evensidemargin\tempmargin
```

To also flip the margin pars, the following line is required

```
\reversemarginpar
```

To flip headers and footers, it is necessary to build a new style that flips everything and then use this style:

```
\defpagestyle{mystyle}{%
{\hfill\headmark}{\headmark\hfill}{\hfill}
}{%
{\hfill\pagemark}{\pagemark\hfill}{\hfill}
}

\pagestyle{mystyle}
```

The following MWE

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum} % only for the example

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\defpagestyle{mystyle}{%
{\hfill\headmark}{\headmark\hfill}{\hfill}
}{%
{\hfill\pagemark}{\pagemark\hfill}{\hfill}
}

\pagestyle{mystyle}

\let\tempmargin\oddsidemargin
\let\oddsidemargin\evensidemargin
\let\evensidemargin\tempmargin
\reversemarginpar

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\lipsum[1-4]

\subsection{A subsection}

\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

should give you exactly what you want:

[image]

Comment: `\automark[subsection]{section}` would be the default anyway in `scrartcl`, when you’d give `automark` as package option. For `scrreprt` or `scrbook` the document class option `open=any` (default in `scrreprt`) or `open=left` is interesting, too. And: Perhaps you should paste the second screenshot with first page left and second right – or add it as third screenshot …

Comment: @Speravir I know `\automark[subsection]{section}` is the default, changed in the answer. About the screenshot, I think that, as it is, it-s better for comparison. :-)